# How to: Pyspark dataframe persist usage and reading-back

Tags: python, dataframe, caching, pyspark, persist

I'm quite new to pyspark, and I'm having the following error:
 `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o517.showString.` and I've read that is due to a lack of memory:
`Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`
So, I've been reading that a turn-around to this situation is to use `df.persist()` and then read again the *persisted* df, so I would like to know:

- Given a `for` loop in which I do some `.join` operations, should I use the `.persist()` inside the loop or at the end of it? e.g.

  ```py
  for col in columns:
     df_AA = df_AA.join(df_B, df_AA[col] == 'some_value', 'outer').persist()

  --> or <--

  for col in columns:
     df_AA = df_AA.join(df_B, df_AA[col] == 'some_value', 'outer')
  df_AA.persist()
  ```

  Once I've done that, how should I read back? 
  `df_AA.unpersist()`? `sqlContext.read.some_thing(df_AA)`?

I'm really new to this, so please,  try to explain as best as you can.

I'm running on a local machine (8GB ram), using jupyter-notebooks(anaconda); windows 7; java 8; python 3.7.1; pyspark v2.4.3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spark is lazy evaluated framework so, none of the **transformations** e.g: join are called until you call an *action*.

So go ahead with what you have done

```
from pyspark import StorageLevel
    for col in columns:
       df_AA = df_AA.join(df_B, df_AA[col] == 'some_value', 'outer')
    df_AA.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    df_AA.show()
```

There multiple persist options available so choosing the **MEMORY_AND_DISK** will spill the data that cannot be handled in memory into DISK.

Also GC errors could be a result of lesser DRIVER memory provided for the Spark Application to run.

Comment: Thanks Joby, and what about reading-back, how can I manage that? should I use a function? or is just about using again the dataframe name within some operation? i.e. df_AA.select('some_col')...etc etc

Comment: @Mike reading back means you want to select some specific columns from the dataframe if yes then what you mentioned in the comment is right `df.select(<columns_list comma separated>)` e.g : `df.select('col1', 'col2')`
To see the data in the dataframe you have to use `df.show()` by default it shows only 20 rows.